# Filtrar SMS de bandeja de entrada por numero de teléfono Android Studio

Tags: java, android, regex, sms

Una consulta. Alguien sabrá cómo filtrar los SMS de entrada por numero de teléfono. Hasta ahora he logrado que me lea todos los mensajes de la bandeja de entrada pero necesitaría filtrarlo también con emisor. Les comparto mi código a ver si alguien sabe cómo puedo llegar a la solución, muchas gracias.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
public static final String INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; //<- Bandeja de entrada

Integer cantmensaje = 1;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_home:

                buscarUbicacion();
                return true;


            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
             //   mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
              //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_apagar:
                //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigationsuperior = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationsuperior);
    navigationsuperior.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigationsuperior.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE





    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE





    final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(!myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Habilitando WIFI!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }



    buscarUbicacion();
}

private void buscarUbicacion() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX), null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() && cantmensaje ==1){
            //int inicio, fin = 0;
            int iniciolatitud, finlatitud, iniciolongitud, finlongitud, finlongitudS = 0;
            String  longitud = "";
            String latitud ="";
            //String cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

            char [] caracteres = cuerpo.toCharArray();


            iniciolatitud = cuerpo.indexOf( "lat:")+4;
            finlatitud = cuerpo.indexOf( "long");
            iniciolongitud = cuerpo.indexOf( "long")+5;
            finlongitud = cuerpo.indexOf( ",T:");
            finlongitudS = cuerpo.indexOf( "speed");
            System.out.println("posicion de inicio LATITUD -->  "+iniciolatitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LATITUD --> "+finlatitud);
            System.out.println("posicion de inicio LONGITUD -->  "+iniciolongitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUD --> "+finlongitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUDS --> "+finlongitudS);
            Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae el CUERPO DEL MENSAJE   "+cuerpo);
           // latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud, finlatitud);
           if (iniciolatitud >= 4){
            if (finlongitudS > finlongitud){

                latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud, finlatitud);
                longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud, finlongitudS);
            }else if ((finlongitudS < finlongitud)) {
                latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud, finlatitud);
                longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud, finlongitud);
            }
           }

            if (iniciolatitud >= 4){

                final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                // webView.loadUrl(""+latitud);
                webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q="+latitud+","+longitud+"&z=16");
                //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                //          } });
                Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q="+latitud+","+longitud+"&z=16");
                //   Log.e("ya viene",""+latitud);

                // }
                Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");
                cantmensaje = cantmensaje + 1;

             //   return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //No hay SMS
        Log.e("PERMISOS","no ingreso a view ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la linea de código:

`String emisor =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));`

se toma el numero del emisor del sms, luego ingreso en el while a recorrer los mensajes de texto en la bandeja de entrada y una vez que encuentro el numero que deseo (en este caso, se trae del archivo `String` de la carpeta `Values`), se toman las partes del SMS que interesan.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;
 //  final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
//  SmsMessage mensajes = SmsMessage.createFromPdu;
public static final String INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; //<- Bandeja de entrada

Integer cantmensaje = 1;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_home:

                buscarUbicacion();
                return true;


            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
             //   mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
              //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_apagar:
                //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigationsuperior = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationsuperior);
    navigationsuperior.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigationsuperior.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE





    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE





    final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(!myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Habilitando WIFI!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }



    buscarUbicacion();
}

private void buscarUbicacion() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX), null, null, null, null);








    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() && cantmensaje ==1){



            //int inicio, fin = 0;
            int iniciolatitud, finlatitud, iniciolongitud, finlongitud, finlongitudS = 0;
            String  longitud = "";
            String latitud ="";

            //String cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")); //TOMA EL CUERPO DE LOS SMS
            String emisor =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")); //TOMA EL NUMERO EMISOR DEL MENSAJE
            char [] caracteres = cuerpo.toCharArray();

            System.out.println("posicion de SMS -->  "+emisor);
            System.out.println("posicion de SMS222222 -->  "+getString(R.string.emisores));
        if (emisor.equals(getString(R.string.emisores))) {    // consulto que el numero de emisor que quiero se encuentre en la bandeja de entrada y tomo la partes del mensaje que me interesan.
            iniciolatitud = cuerpo.indexOf("lat:") + 4;
            finlatitud = cuerpo.indexOf("long");
            iniciolongitud = cuerpo.indexOf("long") + 5;
            finlongitud = cuerpo.indexOf(",T:");
            finlongitudS = cuerpo.indexOf("speed");
            System.out.println("posicion de inicio LATITUD -->  " + iniciolatitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LATITUD --> " + finlatitud);
            System.out.println("posicion de inicio LONGITUD -->  " + iniciolongitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUD --> " + finlongitud);
            System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUDS --> " + finlongitudS);
            Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae el CUERPO DEL MENSAJE   " + cuerpo);
            // latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud, finlatitud);

                if (finlongitudS > finlongitud) {

                    latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitudS);
                } else if ((finlongitudS < finlongitud)) {
                    latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitud);
                }


            if (iniciolatitud >= 4) {

                final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                // webView.loadUrl(""+latitud);
                webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud + "," + longitud + "&z=16");
                //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                //          } });
                Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud + "," + longitud + "&z=16");
                //   Log.e("ya viene",""+latitud);
                Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");
                cantmensaje = cantmensaje + 1;
                 }

                } else {//No hay SMS
                 Log.e("PERMISOS","no ingreso a view ");
                }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Puesto que tú mismo has encontrado la respuesta, podrías hacer lo siguiente: Marcar la respuesta como `wiki de comunidad` y aceptar la respuesta

Comment: hola amigo, cómo estás? me podrías explicar como puedo hacer eso? Gracias

Comment: Edita tu respuesta haciendo click en "editar" y después marca la casilla "wiki de comunidad". Después, simplemente acepta la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mira ahora a ver si te deja "aceptar" la respuesta

Comment: Me dice que puedo aceptar la respuesta dentro de 18 horas. Así que esperaré nomas amigo Julio. Muchas gracias por ese dato que desconocía totalmente